# Rails + Sunspot: "undefined method `populate_instances' ..." error when using date range query facet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, facet

Using [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103077/date-range-facets-with-sunspot-in-ruby-on-rails) from other questions here I have a basic setup for a date range faceted search on the project creation timestamp. First some code:

**/models/project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
   time :created_at, :trie => true
   time :updated_at, :trie => true
  end
end
```

**/controllers/projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  def index
    @search = Project.search do
      bod = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
      facet :created_at do
        row :past do
          with(:created_at).less_than bod - 1.day
        end
        row :today do
          with :created_at, bod
        end
      end
    end
    @projects = @search.results
    respond_with(@projects)
  end
end
```

**/views/projects/index.html.erb**

```
17:  <h3>Created At</h3>
18:  <ul>
19:  <% for row in @search.facet(:created_at).rows %>
20:    <li>
21:      <% if params[:created_at].blank? %>
22:        <%= link_to row.instance.name, :created_at => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
23:      <% else %>
24:        <strong><%= row.instance.name %></strong> (<%= link_to "X", :created_at => nil %>)
25:      <% end %>
26:    </li>
27:  <% end %>
28:  </ul>
```

When I load http://localhost:3000/projects, I get the following error occurring on line #22 from my view:

```
undefined method `populate_instances' for #<Sunspot::Search::QueryFacet:0x00000103669d70>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.